# How to describe someone who often has his own idea and judgment

Tags: word-choice

Suppose someone often has his own idea, opinon and judgment on a lot of things, regardless of whether his agree with others'. I wonder what kinds of words can be used to describe such a quality/characteristic/personality?

**Added:** Such a person does not need to show to others that they are strong-minded, or even may not like to speak out their mind on purpose.

In negative way, I think maybe "stubborn"? Honestly, I feel hurt if being called this way. Am I too sensitive? What else is better?

How about in neutral and positive ways respectively? **Added:** Can "strong-minded" serve the positive purpose?

Comment: "Strong-minded" serves right when you want to be neutral about this quality.

Answer (score 5):

The only way I can think of this quality being expressed in a positive way is with the word **self-assertive**. It means that you aren't afraid to express your own opinions (you certainly have quite a few opinions of your own if you are self-assertive) and that you also feel confident in doing so.

Comment: Thanks! Does "self-assertive" apply whether or not such a person thinks they need to show their mind?

Comment: I think *[self-]assertive* is much the same as *opinionated*, in that it strongly implies one who *expresses* his views more than most, rather than one who tends to have clear-cut opinions but doesn't necessarily push them onto others.

Comment: @Tim: I think FumbleFingers' comment answers your query.

Comment: I think *self-assertive* can be used in a straightforward, complimentary manner (it is a quality you might look for in an employee, for example). But it is so frequently used a a euphemism for boorishness, that you can't really trust it.

Comment: @slim: I don't think a couple of managers discussing the qualities they look for in interview candidates would normally say they want *self-assertive* people. They'd be much more likely to look for *self-confidence*.

Comment: Wordnik defines _self-assertive_ as being "the same as [self-asserting](http://www.wordnik.com/words/self-asserting)." The GNU Webster's definition fits Irene's to a tee, but some of the other definitions are less flattering.

Comment: Isn't *assertive* commonly used in the sense of *self-assertive*? Would someone supporting someone else's opinion be called *assertive*? That way, the prefix *self-* seems redundant.

Answer (score 4):

Iconoclast might seem a little strong for your use, but it has a positive ring to it. Non-conformist can be a compliment.

Answer (score 2):

@slim's *opinionated* covers those cases where a person vociferously announces their views to anyone who will listen, but it's almost always used pejoratively. Often there's the implication that the *opinionated* person has non-standard opinions on anything and everything, purely for the sake of promoting argument/discussion.

For people who know what they think, but doesn't make a habit forcing their thoughts on others, *strong-minded, clear-sighted,* and similar expressions are common. But my favourites are [perspicacious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/perspicacious) - *having keen mental perception and understanding,* and in more informal contexts, [no-nonsense](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/no-nonsense) - *sensible, practical, straightforward.* Both of these strongly imply you're speaking of someone who knows exactly what he thinks, and is not easily persuaded otherwise.

Comment: Perspicacity isn't quite the same thing though. The more I think about it, the more it seems as if the English speaking world is fairly united in condemning strongly held, inflexible opinions.

Comment: @slim: "the English speaking world is fairly united in condemning strongly held, inflexible opinions", really? I feel so sad, although I don't think such a person can not be flexible.

Comment: @Tim, slim: What's wrong with deploring people who hold strong opinions? We live in the "Age of Reason", where hopefully all actual "truths" are broadly agreed on. Only things which are still a matter of debate should be relevant to people holding opinions, and if they hold them too strongly they are in serious danger of failing to recognise when they are in fact mistaken.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "What's wrong with deploring people who hold strong opinions?" do you mean such people are wrong? I feel sad that people that are trying to be perspicacious are taken as stubborn.

Comment: @Tim: Of course not. But if two different people with strong opinions disagree, I suspect that statistically speaking they would be less likely to arrive at the truth of the matter through discussion than two people who are *interested*, yet don't have particularly strong opinions. We only usually admire stubbornly opiniated people much later, **if and when** it turns out that most of us agree with their position.

Answer (score 2):

What about **independent**?

In terms of idioms, the phrase "marches to the beat of a different drummer" comes to mind. (origin from Thoreau's "Walden", the exact quote is a little bit different)

Comment: The person would be an 'independent thinker'.

Answer (score 2):

Autonomous or independent-minded. Both far more positive than strong-minded which is interpreted as merely stubborn or opinionated which is viewed as controversial.

Answer (score 2):

I might call such a person a [*free thinker,*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freethinker) which has roughly the same meaning and connotation as *iconoclast* but is more easily understood.

Answer (score 1):

My own reading of the word "opinionated" seems to fulfil this in a neutral sense. To me it simply means "having many and strong opinions".

However, the two dictionaries I've consulted say "Holding stubbornly and often unreasonably to one's own opinions" and "obstinate or conceited with regard to the merit of one's own opinions". So perhaps it's not what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Is it in a negative sense? How about comparing it to stubborn?

Comment: Can "opinionated" be used whether or not such a person does not need to show to others that they are strong-minded, or even may not like to speak out their mind on purpose??

Comment: I think "opinionated" can serve well for very negative purpose.

Answer (score 1):

A word that expresses holding to your "own idea, opinon and judgment" in a neutral, or even positive way is *[resolute](http://www.wordnik.com/words/resolute)*:

> **resolute**, *adj*.: firm in purpose or belief

Answer (score 1):

One common idiom is that such a person "dances to the beat of their own drum"

The quote comes from Henry David Thoreau:  "If a man does not keep pace with his companions, perhaps it is because he hears a different drummer. Let him step to the music which he hears, however measured or far away."

Comment: Agreed, and good answer, but Jason S already suggested essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

**Maverick**.
Being independent in thought and action or exhibiting such independence http://www.thefreedictionary.com/maverick

Answer (score 0):

**know one's own mind**

> › to be ​certain about what you ​believe or ​want

[Cambridge Advanced Learner’s](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/know-your-own-mind) Dictionary & Thesaurus

Answer (score 0):

I would call them **self-assured**, meaning that they are confident in their own opinions, regardless of the actual validity of them.