# Word to describe someone who does whatever they please?

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m looking for a word that could be used to describe someone that does whatever he wants and doesn't listen to anyone else. Someone like Julius Caesar maybe?

Comment: Julius Caesar wasn't a typical person but an emperor; he didn't do "whatever he pleased". People who do whatever they please can be called "[solipsists](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solipsist)" (those who believe "that the self is the only existent thing") or "[sociopaths](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/psychopath)" ("a mentally ill or unstable individual; especially : one having an antisocial personality"). The nicest words for such people are "inconsiderate" and "egocentric". Anything else is a mealymouthed euphemism.

Comment: Is there a negative connotation? Some are able to listen, but ultimately make their own choice

Answer (score 2):

> [headstrong](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=headstrong&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=uFdCUcjuCfDJ0AXJooCQAQ&sqi=2&ved=0CC4QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=c60bda62866a8f75&biw=1308&bih=887) - Self-willed and obstinate.
>    e.g.: *I am headstrong and like getting my own way*.

Answer (score 1):

> I’m looking for a word that could be used to describe someone that
>   does whatever he wants and doesn't listen to anyone else. Someone like
>   Julius Caesar maybe?

Words (adjectives) that may be used to describe such persons with a negative subtext would include:

- sociopathic; related to actions (which may be violent or dangerous) that are based on selfish motives without regard to laws or the welfare of others.
- megalomaniacal; of actions that are influenced by a strong sense (often delusional) of omnipotence or grandiose power.
- intransigent; related to action or behavior that is stubborn and intractable and not receptive to reason.
- inexorable; of behavior that is relentless and unchangeable

Answer (score 0):

Also see  [What do you call a person who does/thinks the opposite of the crowd for just that reason?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70526) and  [How to describe someone who often has his own idea and judgment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52232), where words such as the following are suggested.

• *[individualist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/individualist)*, “Someone who does as they wish, unconstrained to external influences”
• *[strong-minded](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strong-minded)*, “Having a vigorous, independent will and views”
• *[self-assertive](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/self-assertive#Adjective)*, “determined to advance one's own personality or views”
• *[iconoclast](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iconoclast?rdfrom=Iconoclast#Noun)*, “One who attacks cherished beliefs”  (etc.)
• *[contrarian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contrarian#Noun)*, “a person who expresses a contradicting viewpoint, especially one who denounces the majority persuasion”
• *[opinionated](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/opinionated)*, “Holding to one's own opinion obstinately, stubbornly and unreasonably”
• *[resolute](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/resolute#Adjective)*, “Firm, unyielding, determined”

and per FumbleFingers, “nonconformist, renegade, maverick, rebel, radical, individualist, heretic, dissenter, dissident, iconoclast, loner, etc., etc.”

Comment: Individualist seems most fitting.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, based on its definition, I think so too.  Feel free to vote this up – my vote for it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

While it may have theological implications, **antinomianist** summarizes pretty much all you've described.  An antinomianist makes the rules up as he goes along--as he sees fit.  Antinomianists are a law unto themselves.  They embody relativism and situational ethics in equal measure, with an egocentric twist.  In short, they are more like Epicureans than Stoics, although you could make a case for Stoics' being against the law of appetites, passions, and pleasure, not wanting to come under the domination of such things.  From Greek, anti + nomos, against law.